# How to add an extra parameter to a CNN while training

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

So, I have to train a network where I have an image, ground-truth, and an extra parameter related to an image (current image state).

There's a camera which captures images at different zoom level. For a particular surrounding, I have four images with different zoom levels (0,25,50,75). I need to train the network such that given a test image, I can classify if I want to zoom in or zoom out.

So, the dataset I have is the image, ground-truth (zoom in or zoom out or no zoom), and the current zoom level.

How can I add this current zoom level in my network so that the network trains properly?

I'm planning to use VGG or AlexNet for now and then move to Inception or ResNet in future.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is create a model which processes the image via CNN and then somehow combines other inputs to the model. So your model should have a few inputs: image, (zoom in or zoom out or no zoom), current zoom level. So you pass the image to CNN (or few CNN layers) and then flatten the feature map and append other input values and then continue through some other layers. Or you augment the image on the beginning (if you have to zoom out, zoom out...) and then pass the image to CNN. I don't know which framework are you using but I know I would try to prototype it in Keras with functional API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I thought of something similar. Since the extra input parameter is an integer maybe I can concat in the FC layer. I don’t know how effective that would be. And I’m using TF. Any idea on how I could concat in TF?

Comment: Indeed, add the current zoom level to your dense layers after the C layers.

Comment: You can do it natively in tensorflow, as you would do it in keras functional api. Just be careful with the integer and the scale of other features.

Comment: So, I started with the VGG. Just to confirm, do I use tf.concatenate on the output that I got after the last conv layer? That is I would then pass the result of this tf.concatenate to the next FC layer. Is this approach correct?

Comment: Only if the CNN output is flat vector which I doubt it is. You have to flatten it and then use `tf.concatenate`